# Identify the ASP.NET version of a site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I debug a site. I need to identify the .NET and ASP.NET version of the running site (on a local IIS).

When I have an .NET Error, the a page is displayed, like this:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> *Configuration Error*
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'requestValidationMode'.
>   Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 120:  Line 121:   Line
>   122:       Line 123:       Line
>   124:
>
> Source File: C:\mysite\opt\root\web.config    Line: 122
>
> Version Information: ***Microsoft .NET Framework Version:*** 4.0.30319;
>   **ASP.NET Version:** 4.6.1038.0

Is there a way to obtain that data in other way than a error message, to be able to identify that versions at demand?

I would like to stress that *.NET* and *ASP.NET* are **different**, and I need both of them.

***PS.*** I would prefer, if possible do not have to modify the code, but rather via IIS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try either of this below

```
typeof(Page).Assembly.GetName().Version; //ASP.NET Version
```

This gives your running `ASP.NET` version which in my case `4.0.0.0`. You can find the same information if you expand your `Reference` folder -> find `System.Web` dll -> right click and choose properties -> check the `Version` information.

```
System.Environment.Version.ToString(); //Framework Version
```

This gives the version information of the CLR.

Answer (score 3):

**.NET Framework - registry check?**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Environment.Version
```

should give you the ASP.NET version

Comment: unfortunately registry check does not specify what .net version is used by a concrete site... is just list all available versions on the server.

Comment: fair point. clrver.exe might help see which version is running:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427522(v=vs.110).aspx