# Getting ASP.NET Version programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, version

In some client machines we are having some incompatibility issues related to the .NET Framework.

When a server error is encountered, an error page is displayed. 
On the bottom of the page we have this information:

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1637.0
```

I´ve read different posts and tried multiple things in order to get that value programmatically without success.

This is what I´ve tried:

1)

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version.ToString());
```

Result:

```
4.0.30319.42000
```

2) Programatically reading:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET
```

Result:

```
4.0.30319.0
```

3) Programatically reading:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
```

Result:

```
4.6.01586
```

As you can confirm none of those values map the ASP.NET Version showed in the error page.

So, I have two questions:

1) How can I get the ASP.NET Version programmatically?

2) I faced a case where .NET4.6 was apparently installed but ASP.NET Version was 4.0.30319 (and the suspicion is that this is causing the failure). 
Is there a way to upgrade only ASP.NET? Makes this any sense?

I apologize I don´t have enough reputation to add images.

Comment: Does `typeof(Page).Assembly.GetName().Version; //ASP.NET Version` not work? [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878979/identify-the-asp-net-version-of-a-site)

Comment: It gives me the version of the executing assembly and in my case is 1.0.0.0. (it´s a console app)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to answer to your first question.

You can receive ASP.NET version programmatically like that:

```
var netPath = 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory();
var systemWebPath = Path.Combine(netPath, "System.Web.dll");
if (File.Exists(systemWebPath))
{                
     FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(systemWebPath);
     string version = fileVersionInfo.ProductVersion;
}
```